# Android If-else Style

Tags: android

Just a simple question.
               why above **if-else** Style is Correct in Android.

```
            if(somecondition..A){

                 if(somecondition..B){

                    //Do Something
                 }
            }
```

Instead of

```
           if(somecondition..A)
           {
              if(somecondition..B)
              {
                  //Do Something
              }
            }
```

Source : - [Android Code Style](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

Comment: What is the difference???

Comment: @All pls don't do negative Voting ..it was just a query

Comment: Both are same.dont make everyone laugh.Its a style while you using eclipse tool

Answer (score 2):

Because your write Java codes into Android. So first one is correct style.

By the way your posted code is not match the correct coding style of Android/ Java.

There needs some spaces into your code

```
 if (somecondition..A) {

       if (somecondition..B) {

            //Do Something
       }
 }
```

---

*Every programming language having their own coding style and syntax. There is no problem to write your code into your 2nd given style (And that will run perfectly), but again, we should follow the coding style of used language..*

---

You can read [*Coding Style Wiki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style), and [*Why Coding Style Matters*](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/25/why-coding-style-matters/) or [*WHY YOUR DEVELOPER'S CODING STYLE MATTERS TO YOU*](http://clikfocus.com/blog/why-your-developers-coding-style-matters-you). All three are very good article.

Comment: thanks @pankaj ... because the first if-else style is not traditional and for new Android developer it's bit different.

Comment: @Mario Your most welcome.. :) I think you spent more time with C. No worry u ll do it